# Pass multiple params in django url

Tags: python, regex, django

I have a "viewtree "url that requires multiple input params with arbitrary strings as input.

I have tried the following two implementations of url_patterns:

```
urlpatterns=[
    url(r'^$',views.home,name='home')
    url(r'^(?P<cutoff>.*)/(?P<threshold>.*)/(?P<data_file>.*)/(?P<clustering_func>.*)/(?P<num_groups>.*)',views.viewtree,name='tree')
]
```

and

```
urlpatterns=[
    url(r'^$',views.home,name='home')
    url(r'^(?P<cutoff>.*)-(?P<threshold>.*)-(?P<data_file>.*)-(?P<clustering_func>.*)-(?P<num_groups>.*)',views.viewtree,name='tree')
]
```

Both of these implementations are not working for me and returning syntax errors. I was wondering what exactly the syntax error is and how to fix it. (also did I have my regex .* correct for matching any arbitrary length string).

Also how would I write the action part of a post form in html to send these values from my form to the viewtree view. I currently have something like

```
<form action="{% url 'appname:viewtree' cutoff threshold data_file clustering_func num_groups %}" method ="post">
     rest of form
</form>
```

Comment: "I was wondering what exactly the syntax error is" - Same here, care to tell us?

Comment: It literally just says syntax error, invalid syntax at line 6 where line 6 is the 2nd url. And I'm just trying to match an arbitrary length string, because each of my arguments is supposed to be a string that I pass into the viewtree function

Comment: Also, `.*` is a very broad regex, what are you trying to match? Please provide examples of url's you are trying to create

Comment: I think syntax error is because of missing ',' symbol after first url?

Comment: As @Nick mentioned, you lack a trailing comma after your first url pattern.
`url(r'^$',views.home,name='home')` should be `url(r'^$',views.home,name='home'),`.

Comment: I love you so much @Nick Thank you! Been coding for 30 hours straight. If anybody could help me with the form's syntax too that would be phenomenal

Comment: `rest of form` should be `{{ form }}`, without more information its not possible to help any more

Comment: How do the cutoff, threshold and others variables that you mention in form' action attribute get their values? Do you pass them through the context? Or is they just fields of this form?

Comment: They're just fields. But I fixed this thank you